# Shopware 6 : How to use the `CategoryIndexerEvent` available in Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event

Tags: shopware6

I want to use the `Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event\CategoryIndexerEvent.php` in my plugin.

Does anyone know how to use this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [EventSubscriber](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/register-subscriber). For the event you mentioned this would look something like this.

First you need a event subscriber:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\CategoryEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event\CategoryIndexerEvent;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_INDEXER_EVENT => 'doMyStuff'
        ];
    }

    public function doMyStuff(CategoryIndexerEvent $event): void
    {
        $indexedCategories = $event->getIds();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And second you need to register this Subscriber in the DIC (plugin/src/Resources/config/services.xml) :

```
<!-- ... -->
<service id="MyPlugin\MySubscriber">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: hey thanks for answer. do you know when this event will execute? i mean on category add / update?

Comment: This event is fired as soon as categories are indexed. This is an asyncronous process. If you want to do something on each category change or write chose the CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_WRITTEN_EVENT instead.